# MVC2 ActionResult not executing when DropDownList changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC 2 and ran into a slight issue which I can't seem to figure out.

Basically I have a drop down which is populated from an Access db and when the user selects a value I would like to call an ActionResult passing through the selected value as a parameter, I'm trying to achieve this by using `$.post`

The drop down is getting populated with data and I can confirm that the javascript function fires but the break point in my ActionResult is still not being hit, I'd appreciate any advice:

**Model:**

```
public class SuppliersModel
{
    public SuppliersModel()
    {
    }

    public SuppliersModel(string id)
    {
    }

    private string id;
    public string ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public SelectList OurSuppliers
    {
        get 
        {
            List<SelectListItem> suppliers = GetSuppliers();
            var list = new SelectList(suppliers, "Value", "Text");
            return list;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> UniqueSuppliers{get;set;}

    private List<SelectListItem> GetSuppliers()
    {
        var suppliers = new List<SelectListItem>();
        string conn = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;

        using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(conn))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string commandText = "SELECT [Supplier], [ID] FROM [Suppliers] ORDER BY [Supplier]";
            using (var command = new OleDbCommand(commandText, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string id = reader["ID"].ToString();
                        string supplier = reader["Supplier"].ToString();
                        suppliers.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = supplier, Value = id });
                    }
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
            return suppliers;
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class SuppliersController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Suppliers()
    {
        SuppliersModel model = new SuppliersModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SuppliersById(string id)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        SuppliersModel model = new SuppliersModel(id);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#suppliers').change(function () {
                debugger;
                $.post('@Url.Action("SuppliersById", "Suppliers")', { id: $(this).val() }, 
                function (result) {
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <h2>
        Suppliers</h2>
    <div>
        <%= Html.DropDownList("suppliers",Model.OurSuppliers) %>
    </div>
    <% if (Model.ID != null)
       { %>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <h2>
                List of suppliers
                </h2>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <% foreach (var item in Model.UniqueSuppliers)
           { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) %>
                |
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })%>
                |
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
    <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Might be worth adding Glimpse (http://getglimpse.com/), which would tell you if it's a routing issue...

Comment: Try viewing the post in Fiddler, you should see the route it's going to and the content it's posting. You could also just try building the post up in Fiddler and posting that way.

Comment: Open up your browser's javascript console (F12) and watch where it is trying to post to. Maybe you are getting a 404 due to some routing issue and you don't know it. Also, your POST method needs to return Json() instead of View(). View() will return html, which I don't think is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a syntax error in my javascript function, this fixed it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#suppliers').change(function () {
            $.post('<%=Url.Action("SuppliersById", "Suppliers")%>', { id: $(this).val() }, 
            function (result) {
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```